# Visual Studio project launches at incorrect URL

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc, visual-studio, iis

I have an ASP.NET MVC project in Visual Studio. When running the project, Google Chrome launches but a 'This site can’t be reached' error is shown, and I notice that the `https` prepended to the URL instead of `http`. Can anyone advise?

**Steps I have taken:**

IIS Manager:

- Added binding `http://mysite.local` on Port 80
- Set physical path to the project folder root (the same level as the 'App_Data' folder), and set permissions to the `IIS_IUSRS` group to this folder

Visual Studio:

- Server: Local IIS
- Project URL: http://mysite.local
- Override application root URL: http://mysite.local

Windows Hosts file:

- Added entry: `127.0.0.1 mysite.local`

Comment: Do you have `<rewriteRules>` at your web.config?

Comment: @VictorLeontyev No rewrite rules are present

Comment: Is it happens in all browsers? Or only Chrome

Comment: Do you have the HTTPS everywhere extension for Chrome perhaps? Or one of the more manual methods of forcing HTTPS enabled?

Comment: I changed the launch browser in Visual Studio and it also happens in Internet Explorer.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Visual Studio website is redirecting http to https when debugging](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/26501670/visual-studio-website-is-redirecting-http-to-https-when-debugging)

Comment: Having the same problem after updating Chrome. Just open an other window of Chrome and run your URL there.

Answer (score 0):

Please check whether in your project SSL is enabled or not? You can find it in the properties section of your project like below image:

[image]

Answer (score 0):

In Visual studio select the project in solution explorer and set the SSL to false.
Check same in project settings and set the project url to HTTP one there too.

In your MVC Controller :- make sure you didn't apply things like [RequireHttps](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.web.mvc.requirehttpsattribute%28v=vs.118%29.aspx)